# How to prevent WCF proxy from following redirect?

Tags: wcf

I'm using basicHttpBinding for my WCF service and have a message inspector that sets response code to Redirect under certain circumstances. I find that the WCF proxy (generated by svcutil) automatically tries to follow the redirect. How do I prevent this from happening?

Thanks,
Priya

Answer (score 0):

Can you reference the service contract assembly from your client application? If so you can get rid of the generated service reference and just spin up a proxy at runtime using ChannelFactory.

For example:

```
// Create service proxy on the fly
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyServiceContract>("NameOfMyClientEndpointInConfigFile");
var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

// Create data contract
var requestDataContract = new MyRequestType();

// Call service operation.
MyResponseType responseDataContract = proxy.MyServiceOperation(requestDataContract);
```

In the above example, `IMyServiceContract` is your service contract, and `MyRequestType` and  `MyResponseType` are your data contracts, which you can use by referencing the assembly which the service also references (which defines these types).

Answer (score 0):

what have you tried to achieve with redirect ? you will an handle this cases with some message interceptors on client side:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733786(v=vs.90).aspx